# Error: cannot find module object-assign after upgrading to react ^15.3 and react-dom ^15.3 for Proptypes warning

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-proptypes

I have been getting the warning in my console about deprecation of Proptypes directly from React.

```
bundle.js:9748 Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.* prop-types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility, migration and more...
```

So, I installed prop-types per the Facebook github page, and migrated the code.

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

But the warning did not go away since I did not have React and React-dom 15.3 so I upgraded them both. After which, I got the error and my app stopped running:

```
Error: Cannot find module object-assign
```

I tried installing object-assign but that did not get rid of the error or get the app running again.

```
npm install object-assign --save-dev
```

How can I fix this problem and get rid of the Proptypes console warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to a node module that was not fully upgraded. I searched the entire node modules directory using the search function on atom for "PropTypes } from 'react'" and react-router-dom came up. I upgraded the package to the most recent one and the warning was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Well the warning seems like you are importing `Proptypes` directly from `react` rather than using `prop-types`. If you change to use the `Proptypes` from `prop-types` package/module, it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that I had one slightly dated version of react-router-dom that imported propTypes from react. I upgraded it and the warning was gone.